# How to lock accounts after a certain number of invalid login attempts

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an authentication scheme in my oracle apex application. I also have the end users username and passwords stored in the database. So when a user logs in, they use their username and password they made (i dont make any account for the user). I want to set it up so that accounts get locked if they make too many invalid login attempts (which i should be able to unlock).

Form what ive researched the only thing i can find is something to do with administration express but i was still clueless as to how this helped nor could i find this page in my oracle application. I also dont want anything to complicated, perhaps something that is on apex rather than code (since i am not that great at understanding functions/booleans etc).

Comment: Hi, Are you using custom Authentication Scheme or using the default `Application Express Accounts` Scheme?

Comment: I am using a custom authentication scheme

Comment: I hope those passwords are not stored in plain text.

Answer (score 2):

For Application Express Account Authentication,
It applies to end-user accounts created using the Application Express end-user account management interface.

Login to the `Internal` Workspace and Go to `Manage Instance > Security > Authentication Control`,Go to `Development Environment Settings`  and set `Require User Account Expiration and Locking` to Yes. [image]

For Custom Authentication,I hope you can log the invalid user attempts in the log table and restrict/lock the users based on the count of consecutive invalid login attempts.

Below sample code is based on the [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4175902) provided

Create a USER_LOG table to log invalid attempts as shown below

```
create table USER_LOG (username varchar2(4000), 
                       login_failed_count number, updated_on date);
```

Alter the existing `table1` and add a flag (Y - Yes User locked, N - No User not locked ) for User Lock as shown below.

```
Alter table table1 add is_locked varchar2(1) default 'N';
```

After doing the above changes, you can try with the below updated procedure provided in the link.

```
create or replace function Table1Authenticate( p_username varchar2, p_password varchar2 ) return boolean is  
   i integer;  
   l_rcnt number;
   l_failed_cnt number;
   l_max_failed_cnt number :=4;
   l_lock_flag varchar2(1);
begin     
    select  count(1)  into l_rcnt 
     from table1 t1  
     where t1.username = p_username  
     and   t1.password = p_password;

       if (l_rcnt > 0) then
          select is_locked into l_lock_flag from table1 where username = p_username
          and password = p_password;

          if (l_lock_flag ='N') then
             delete from USER_LOG where username=p_username;
             return true;
          elsif (l_lock_flag ='Y') then 
            apex_util.set_custom_auth_status (p_status => 'Account Locked, Exceeded Maximum Attempts..!');
            return false;
          end if;
       else
           merge into USER_LOG u
           using dual l
           on (u.username=p_username)
             when matched then
                update set login_failed_count=login_failed_count+1,updated_on=sysdate 
             when not matched then
                insert (username,login_failed_count,updated_on) values
                (p_username,1,sysdate);

           select login_failed_count into l_failed_cnt 
           from user_log where username =p_username;
              if (l_failed_cnt > l_max_failed_cnt) then
                 update table1 set is_locked='Y' where username=p_username;
              end if;
            return( false );  
       end if;
   exception when others then  
           return( false );  
end;
```

To unlock the user, update the `is_locked` in `table1` from `Y` to `N`. Please validate with multiple scenarios before using it. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I cant find the manage instance button, whereabouts is it located

Comment: This is for `Application Express Accounts` authentication sheme. You have to login to the `INTERNAL` workspace with Admin Credentials

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by internal workspace. I can log into oracle application express but i dont thinki have admin credentials.

Comment: For Custom Authentication,I hope you can log the invalid user attempts in the log table and restrict/lock the users based on the count of consecutive invalid login attempts

Comment: Do you have any idea how i might do this or the example of the code. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to suggest  if you share your sample authentication code

Comment: The INTERNAL workspace is what you type in the 'workspace' field upon the builder login. There must be relevant user in apex_workspace_apex_users table.

Comment: I have copied the code from this website almost exactly https://community.oracle.com/thread/4175902

Comment: I will update the code  in the same answer based on the link provided